# SpringXD: messages don't include headers when a message is read from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-xd

I have the following structure:

- A kafka topic
- A module for my kafka sink/source
- A module that comes after the kafka source. Basically to read what the kafka source is sending.

The problem is, when the kafka sink sends events to the kafka Queue, and the kafka source has received a message from the kafka topic, AND then, the next module tries to read the headers, it fails because no headers are found.

I propose the following solution: To wrap the headers inside a message, so with this, the inner payload will contain a the original payload + headers.

What another option do I have?.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kafka does not natively support headers, the exact mechanism you describe is supported by the Kafka Message Bus - it's just that you have to opt-in the header names you want transported by the bus, to avoid transporting headers that are not needed.

See [Application Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#application-configuration).

Scroll down to the Kafka message bus properties.

```
messagebus:
 kafka:
  # connection properties
  brokers:                                localhost:9092  (1)
  zkAddress:                              localhost:2181  (2)
  socketBufferSize:                       2097152         (3)
  # operating mode
  mode:                                   embeddedHeaders (4)
  offsetManagement:                       kafkaTopic      
  headers:
  # comma-delimited list of additional header names to transport (6)
  ...
```

> 6. A list of custom headers to be transported by the bus.

**EDIT**

For rabbit, all headers are transported by default:

```
    replyHeaderPatterns:       STANDARD_REPLY_HEADERS,*   
    ...
    requestHeaderPatterns:     STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS,*
```

**EDIT**

If you mean you wish to use the same technique to send/receive from Kafka using the sink/source then you can use the support classes from XD for that - see `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter`. The header values are encoded as JSON.

Comment: That means that I should have to change the data transport that we have been using since the last year (we are using rabbit). it doesn't sound as a good deal, I mean if I change the data transport to Kafka. Should be the option that I describe the more suitable solution in case of I don't want to change the data transport?

Comment: If you are using Rabbit as a transport, all the headers are transported (mapped to rabbitmq headers); it is only for the kafka transport that you have to configure which headers are transported. The rabbit transport can be configured to restrict the headers, but by default, all are sent.

Comment: If you mean you wish to use the same technique to send/receive from Kafka using the sink/source then you can use the support classes from XD for that - see `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter`. The header values are encoded using JSON.